NextJs 14 App Router - how to load a single server component on demand?
Is there a way to render a page statically with a server component rendered on demand?
In the example below, I'd like Home page to be statically rendered in the build time so that the document request can be cached but keep ServerComponent dynamic, loaded on demand.
export default function Home(){
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Page title</h1>
      <Suspense loading="Loading..."><ServerComponent/></Suspense>
    </>
  )
}

I'm aware this can be achieved partially via streaming, but in this case, the page isn't static, it's generated on each request.
I also understand that I can achieve this by using a client component but I'm curious is it possible to get such behavior with a server component?

I speculate you might want to render the page in SSG. try reading this
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params

Not really, I was just looking to see if it's possible to load a single server component with suspense without loading the whole page
